# Не работает set_cookie() в Tornado

Tags: python, cookie, tornado

Добрый вечер, по какому-то неясному мне случаю, не работает self.set_cookie(), который должен записывать куку для пользователя. 
Еще более интересно то, что для первой линии в файле - все работает, но не для последующих. При этом, я точно знаю, что пользователь в файле находится и все доходит до self.set_cookie(...), но сам метод не выполняет то, что ему надлежит.

```
class LoginHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def post(self):
        login = self.get_argument("login", "")
        pswrd = self.get_argument("pswrd", "")
        if login and pswrd:
            f = open(DB, "r")
            lines = f.readlines()
            f.close()
            for line in lines:
                line = line.replace("\n","")
                line = line.replace("'","\"")
                line = json.loads(line)
                if line["login"] == login and line["password"] == pswrd:
                    self.set_cookie("user", "{}:verified".format(login))
                else:
                    signin(self)
        else:
            signin(self)
```

Comment: Может дело в том, что после вызова `set_cookie` больше ничего не делается? Какой-то ответ клиенту стоит вернуть.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev тогда бы оно не работало и для первого пользователя в файле, но для него - работает

Comment: Попробуйте заменить метод post на get и посмотреть установятся ли куки. В вашем варианте, куки не устанавливаются вообще, даже дл первой линии.

Comment: @Avernial хорошо, попробую